# I need to run a script that might break `apt-get` database. What should I backup?

Tags: apt, package-management, backup

I'm working on a wrapper script for `rm` that might break `apt-get` part way through processing.

What file(s) do I need to back up first in case `apt-get` database gets corrupted?

Comment: Also asked this on [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2348345)  since am also curious about it to. Hope some help will come soon :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging,i found out that `apt-get` database is managed by `dpkg`

From [`man dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg.1.html)

```
   /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg
          Configuration file with default options.

   /var/log/dpkg.log
          Default log file (see /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg(5) and option --log).

   The other files listed below are in their default directories, see option --admindir to see how to
   change locations of these files.

   /var/lib/dpkg/available
          List of available packages.

   /var/lib/dpkg/status
          Statuses  of  available packages. This file contains information about whether a package is
          marked for removing or not, whether it is installed or not, etc.  See  section  INFORMATION
          ABOUT PACKAGES for more info.

          The  status  file is backed up daily in /var/backups. It can be useful if it's lost or cor‐
          rupted due to filesystems troubles.
```

Also from [The Debian FAQ](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html),it says

> It is important to understand that the higher level package management
>   tools such as aptitude or synaptic rely on apt which, itself, relies
>   on dpkg to manage the packages in the system.

So if `dpkg` puts its own database in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, that means `apt-get` database and all other package mangers maintained by `dpkg` will also be in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.So simply by backing up `/var/lib/dpkg/status` (of which `dpkg` already puts its backups in `/var/backups/`) will solve your worries of screwing up with `apt-get`.

Comment: Also when you use `ll /var/lib/dpkg/*old` you see `status` is one of the four files with on-line backups there. Thanks for your quick research!

Comment: In case you are wondering the `rm` wrapper script worked perfectly and didn't break `apt-get` so the database never got corrupted. Knowing before hand what could break was reassuring though.

Comment: Yes,glad no harm occurred :) !that is called defensive mechanism,its better to taking measures of stopping the problem than fixing it.